# How to set default Ruby version with RVM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, ruby-1.9.2

Ubuntu 11.

I do the following:

`$ rvm --default use 1.9.2`
and I get:

`Using /home/md/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180`
so that is good.

but when I now open a new terminal window I still get:

`$ ruby -v`

`ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i686-linux]`

Comment: What version of rvm? I'm on Ubuntu 10, but I'm skeptical that'd be able to make a difference. Anything in ~/.rvmrc?

Comment: What happens if you run `rvm list default` in a new terminal window?

Comment: Try running `rvm --default 1.9.2` instead. That works for me.

Comment: Did you accidentally put the line to load rvm in your `bashrc` instead of your `bash_profile`?

Comment: jsdeseno yes I actually had it in both.  I removed the .bashrc one but this did not help.  I still have the path at the bottom, e.g. `PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/durrantm/.rvm/bin:/home/durrantm/.rvm/bin:/home/durrantm/Downloads/android/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools:/Downloads/android/android-sdk-linux_x86/platform-tools`

Comment: bricker, rvm list default gives: `Default Ruby (for new shells)

   ruby-1.9.2-p180 [ i386 ]
`

Comment: both a new shell ruby -v gives 1.8.7

Comment: martin, that is good but does not affect a new shell window's ruby -v

Comment: Dave - `durrantm@michael-laptop:~$ cat .rvmrc
export rvm_path="/home/durrantm/.rvm"
durrantm@michael-laptop:~$ cat .rvm
cat: .rvm: Is a directory
durrantm@michael-laptop:~$ ls .rvm
archives  config   environments  gems     help  LICENCE  man      README  scripts  tmp   usr      wrappers
bin       contrib  examples      gemsets  lib   log      patches  rubies  src      user  VERSION
durrantm@michael-laptop:~$`

Comment: Please note that the order is wrong in the command you typed!  the "--default" option goes right after the "rvm use" , followed by the version number, e.g. "rvm use --default 1.9.2"

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If you put the RVM source line in your bashrc (in order to ensure that non-interactive shells have access to RVM), you will need to source .bashrc from your .bash_profile with the following as the last lines in your .bash_profile

```
if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
  source $HOME/.bashrc
fi
```

This pre-supposes that you have

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

in your $HOME/.bashrc. This is a good way to ensure that both interactive/login and non-interactive shells are able to find and load RVM correctly. Multi-User installs accomplish the same thing via the /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh file.

After that, you should have no problems defining a default Ruby to use via

```
rvm 1.9.2 --default
```

or

```
rvm use 1.9.2@mygemset --default
```

Its better to define a default gemset to use so as not to pollute your 'default' or 'global' gemsets.

If you are using non-interactive shells, be aware that they genereally operate in SH-compatibility mode which then requires you to set

```
BASH_ENV="$HOME/.bashrc"
```

in your $HOME/.profile in order you load RVM, or to set that within your script directly. The reason for this is that when bash is operating in SH mode it does not directly load .bash_profile or .bashrc as SH doesn't use those files, and bash is attempting to mimic the loading and execution process of the SH shell.

Answer (score 39):

do an "rvm list" to see which Ruby versions you have installed.

then do this if you want to change the version only in one terminal session:

```
rvm use 1.8.7
```

if you want to select the default version for this user account, do this:

```
rvm use --default 1.9.2
```

See:

```
rvm use --help
```

See also this RailsCast:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/200-rails-3-beta-and-rvm

http://beginrescueend.com/

Answer (score 4):

Late to party - anyway.

You did correctly set the default ruby version: `rvm --default use 1.9.2`

However, you need to update your `Gemfile` to the target ruby, because RVM references that file to select the working ruby version when you open terminal , that's why it reverted to the previous ruby version.

Answer (score 0):

To Change the Default Version of ruby:

In **Ubuntu**

*Go to default Terminal of Ubuntu and then follow the instructions:*

```
1) Edit -> Profile Preferences
2) Select "Title and Command"
3) check "Run command as a login shell"
4) restart terminal
```

And after that run this command:

> rvm --default use 2.2.4@gemset_name