# Upgrade to ruby 1.9.3 from 1.8.7 (rvm)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I have to upgrade from ruby 1.8.7 to ruby 1.9.3; I'm trying to install refinery cms and it uses truncate_html gem, which depends on ruby (>= 1.9). I've installed ruby 1.9.3-p374 without removing ruby 1.8.7.

I've used the command `rvm --default use 1.9.3` and it issued the result

```
Using /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374
```

but when i type `ruby -v` it was again 1.8.7.

How can I upgrade to ruby 1.9.3?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installed Ruby 1.9.3 with RVM but command line doesn't show ruby -v](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056008/installed-ruby-1-9-3-with-rvm-but-command-line-doesnt-show-ruby-v)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696633/rails-rvm-how-to-set-default-ruby-version-for-new-terminal-window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using RVM Ubuntu package which is broken, use this instructions to update https://stackoverflow.com/a/9056395/497756

Answer (score -1):

Are you using a .rvmrc file for your project? If so, it might be selecting a specific Ruby over your default.

Open `./.rvmrc` if it exists and remove (as necessary) any `rvm use...` references.

Answer (score -1):

Try

`ruby1.9.1 <filename.rb>`

Comment: or ruby1.9.3 <filename.rb>