# Need to set ruby version each time a terminal session is started

Tags: ruby, rvm

I use `rvm` on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine and each time I start the terminal, the ruby version selected (from `ruby -v`) is `ruby 1.9.3p551` . `rvm --default use 2.2.3` lets me use the selected ruby version, but the entire process needs to be redone each time a new session is started.

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in your gemfile if there is a references to 1.9.3

If not, check this answer and follow the instructions [How to set default Ruby version with RVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696633/how-to-set-default-ruby-version-with-rvm)

Comment: thanks. I removed 1.9.3 from my list of rubies and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.ruby-version` file. 
This file checked by both ruby version managers, like [`rvm`](https://rvm.io/workflow/projects#supported-files) and [`rbenv`](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#choosing-the-ruby-version).

For example you can place a file `.ruby-version` with `2.2.3` in the home directory `~/.ruby-version`, it is should set the ruby version at `2.2.3` for any new terminal session. Also you can place a file `.ruby-version` in the project directory,  `/path/to/the/project/.ruby-version` it is should set ruby version for project.