# How can I use the latest version of Ruby by default?

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal, rvm

I am on a Mac running OSX 10.11 El Capitan. I installed Ruby 2.3.1 via rvm. If I type in the terminal

```
ruby --version
```

It says that I am running 2.0.0

But if I type

```
rvm use 2.3.1
```

And then

```
ruby --version
```

It says that I am running 2.3.1

But next time I open terminal it goes back to 2.0.0

How can I use latest version of Ruby by default?

Answer (score 1):

```
rvm --default use 2.3.1
```

Documentation [here](https://rvm.io/rubies/default).

Comment: Hmm, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696633/how-to-set-default-ruby-version-with-rvm) answer offers another solution. Let me know if that solves the problem or not.

Answer (score 0):

Make a `.ruby-version` file in a directory of your project and in it put `ruby-3.2.1` or which ever version you want