# Heroku deploy Ruby 2.6.1 : warn_for_outdated_bundler_version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bundler

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53231667/you-must-use-bundler-2-or-greater-with-this-lockfile), but the proposed solutons didn't work for me.

I'm trying to deploy a `Rails 5.2` application with `Ruby 2.6.1`, but I keep getting this error in the deployment phase:

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:108:in `warn_for_outdated_bundler_version': You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile. (Bundler::LockfileError)
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:95:in `initialize'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:83:in `new'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:83:in `initialize'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:234:in `new'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:234:in `to_definition'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:13:in `evaluate'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:34:in `build'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler.rb:135:in `definition'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler.rb:101:in `setup'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /app/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /app/bin/rake:2:in `require_relative'
from /app/bin/rake:2:in `<main>'
```

What I find strange in this error is this line:

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:108:in `warn_for_outdated_bundler_version': You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile. (Bundler::LockfileError)
```

Heroku seems to say it is using `Ruby 2.6.0`. But in the build phase, it says it uses `Ruby 2.6.1` with `Bundler 2`:

```
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.6.1
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.0.1
```

The build is successful, but the deployment is in failure.

Here is how is configured my app.

**Gemfile** (reduced to what matters)

```
ruby "2.6.1"
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2'
```

**Gemfile.lock** (reduced to what matters)

```
RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.6.1p33

BUNDLED WITH
   2.0.1
```

On heroku, my buildpack is `heroku/ruby`. My stack is `heroku-18`.

Heroku seems to be supporting `Bundler 2`, as said in [this post](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/6784#issuecomment-465216349).

Any idea on what could fail in the deployment?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. The problem was at deploy time, not during the build. The deployment was using Ruby 2.6.0, because of Heroku's web dyno that is by default:

```
rails server -p $PORT -e $RAILS_ENV
```

Yet, [this post from bundler github](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/6784#issuecomment-467214314) is telling to prefix every single command with `bundle exec`. But the `rails server` command from the dyno is not prefixed so.

A workaround I found is modifying the project `Procfile` file, and add the following line:

```
web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT -e $RAILS_ENV
```

This way, the `rails server` command uses the expected `Ruby version`, the `2.6.1` insteand of the `2.6.0` that generated the error.