# Docker: You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile

Tags: ruby, docker, bundler

I am trying to install bundler version `2.1` in a docker image that is built from `ruby:2.4.1`. My Docker file looks the following way:

```sh
FROM ruby:2.4.1

RUN \
  gem update --system --quiet && \
  gem install  bundler -v '~> 2.1'

# Other commands
```

But when I try to run `bundle install` it fails with

```
You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.
```

When I run inside a container `gem info bundler` it outputs:

```
bundler (2.1.2, 1.15.4)
    Authors: André Arko, Samuel Giddins, Colby Swandale, Hiroshi
    Shibata, David Rodríguez, Grey Baker, Stephanie Morillo, Chris
    Morris, James Wen, Tim Moore, André Medeiros, Jessica Lynn Suttles,
    Terence Lee, Carl Lerche, Yehuda Katz
    Homepage: https://bundler.io
    License: MIT
    Installed at (2.1.2): /usr/local/bundle
                 (1.15.4): /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0
```

I tried the following fixes:

```sh
# Set bundler 2.1.2 as default
bundler config default 2.1.2

# Update bundler
gem update bundler
```

But they didn't work. The system continues to use bundler `v1.15.4`

How can I make bundler `v2.1.2` as default inside a ruby docker image?

Comment: Possible duplicate [Bundler: You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53231667/bundler-you-must-use-bundler-2-or-greater-with-this-lockfile)

Comment: What's the version number in your `Gemfile.lock`; is it exactly 2.1.2?  Can you edit your question to include the relevant `COPY` and `RUN` Dockerfile instructions that reproduce this?

Comment: @DavidMaze Gemfile.lock has `BUNDLED WITH 2.1.1`. I guess that any bundler version greater than `2.0.0` would be OK. I use docker image from the question to run builds with Gitlab CI, and there are no RUN and COPY commands that reproduce the issue. These commands are located in `.gitlab-ci.yml`. I will update my question, thank you

Comment: Bundler 2.1 has [a pretty significant bug](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/7489) that you must have _exactly_ the bundler version named in the `Gemfile.lock` version installed.  The symptom isn't quite what you describe here, but semantic-version constraints don't work any more.  Does `gem install bundler -v 2.1.1` make a difference?

Comment: Can you remove v1.15.4 with gem uninstall?

Comment: @simonwo possibly removing the old bundler version will work - I haven't tried it yet. I've already found [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59722212/3676469) that is working for me

Comment: @DavidMaze in the issue you mentioned rubygems are complaining that the older bundler version that the previous release was deployed with is missing. At the other hand in this issue bundler is complaining that the new version of bundler is expected

Comment: @TamerShlash [the first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53231667/bundler-you-must-use-bundler-2-or-greater-with-this-lockfile#comment98008635_53231667) to the question you mentioned as a possible duplicate helped me to answer my question. Not sure if my question is a duplicate because I got this error in a Docker container although the OQ relates to Heroku environment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to switch to bundler version 2.1 in my docker image using the following commands:

```sh
# Dockerfile
RUN \
  gem update --system --quiet && \
  gem install  bundler -v '~> 2.1'
ENV BUNDLER_VERSION 2.1
```

Answer (score -3):

For using previous version, try this fix. Looks like issue with Gemfile.lock. Try **removing** BUNDLED WITH from gemfile.lock.

Remove something like and build again

```
BUNDLED WITH
   2.1.4
```