# I can not access the rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I can not access the rails console , I'm working with MAC Mojave. 
I have tried to solve with the following alternatives, but the same error still appears.

https://gist.github.com/wbotelhos/46c37807c834ccb5bb406e426adfe347

if I open a new terminal and write ruby ​​-v, ruby ​​appears 2.3.7
but some time ago, I deleted this version of ruby.

but I can not erase it definitively, since I open a new terminal and version 2.3.7 keeps appearing.

```
    rails cRunning via Spring preloader in process 42876
    /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require': dlopen(/Users/adriantapia/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/readline.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib (LoadError)
      Referenced from: /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/readline.bundle
      Reason: image not found - /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/readline.bundle
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb/completion.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in lookup'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:78:in `each'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:78:in `block in lookup'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:77:in `each'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:77:in `lookup'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rails/command.rb:68:in `find_by_namespace'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rails/command.rb:42:in `invoke'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
            from /Users/adriantapia/Desktop/Proyectos/first_web/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `block in load'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
            from -e:1:in `<main>'
    Adrians-MacBook-Pro:first_web adriantapia$ rails c
    Running via Spring preloader in process 43094
    /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require': dlopen(/Users/adriantapia/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/readline.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib (LoadError)
      Referenced from: /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/readline.bundle
      Reason: image not found - /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/readline.bundle
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb/completion.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in lookup'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:78:in `each'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:78:in `block in lookup'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:77:in `each'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:77:in `lookup'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rails/command.rb:68:in `find_by_namespace'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rails/command.rb:42:in `invoke'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
            from /Users/adriantapia/Desktop/Proyectos/first_web/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `block in load'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
            from /Users/adriantapia/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
            from -e:1:in `<main>'


My RVM: rvm list
   ruby-2.4.1 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.4.4 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.5.1 [ x86_64 ]

ruby -v :
    ruby 2.4.4p296 (2018-03-28 revision 63013) [x86_64-darwin18]

rails -v:
Rails 5.1.6.1
```

Comment: I added this gem (gem 'rb-readline', '~> 0.5.3')
to the development group and it was solved, but this problem happens in new projects and I would have to add this gem always, how can I solve it definitively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using RVM you can set the ruby version to each specific ruby project.  You go to the project folder, then type:

```
rvm list
#will return list of all installed rubies and which one you're currently using, for example:

   ruby-2.1.10 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.2 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.3.4 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.3.5 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.3.6 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.3.7 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.4.1 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.5.1 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.6.1 [ x86_64 ]
```

Then to select which ruby version you want for this project:

```
rvm use 2.6.1 # will set RVM to use this version locally from this directory
```

To set the default RVM version on any new project or where a local version has not been set:

```
rvm use 2.6.1 --default
```

In your Rails project's Gemfile you can also set the ruby version, you should have a line like:

```
ruby '~> 2.6.1'
```

For each ruby version you'll likely need to run this at least once on a rails project if it's the first time you're using it with that ruby version to install gems for that project:

```
bundle install
```

For more information see [How to set default Ruby version with RVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696633/how-to-set-default-ruby-version-with-rvm)

Answer (score 2):

You probably compiled your Ruby version against `libreadline.7.dylib` but updated to `libreadline.8.dylib` recently – for example by running `brew upgrade`.

Now Ruby complains that it doesn't find `libreadline.7.dylib` anymore in the `/usr/local/opt/readline/lib/` folder.

To fix this issue navigate to that folder and list its content

```
$ cd /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/
$ ls -l
```

You will probably see something like this:

```
... libreadline.8.0.dylib
... libreadline.8.dylib -> libreadline.8.0.dylib
```

Then just create a new symlink for the missing old version:

```
$ ln -s libreadline.8.0.dylib libreadline.7.dylib
```

The first file is the one that is existing on your computer and was listed by `ls -l`. And the second file is one that is missing which was named in the error message.

Answer (score 2):

It can also be possible because of the spring issue. Try restarting it by using the following commands:

`bin/spring stop`

`bin/spring start`